# MongoDB: Using $elemMatch on array of numbers or strings

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a user rating (thumbs up / thumbs down) for items (products) in my app.

I seem to be able to achieve what I want with an array of objects, but I am wondering if mongodb provides a way to do this with arrays of numbers (user_ids).

```
db.items.insert({up: 2, down: 3, u_up: [{id: 1}, {id:2}], u_down: [3,4,5]})
db.items.insert({up: 3, down: 3, u_up: [{id: 1}, {id:2}, {id:3}], u_down: [7,8,9]})
db.items.insert({up: 0, down: 0, u_up: [], u_down: []})
db.items.insert({up: 2, down: 2, u_up: [{id:2},{id:3}], u_down: [7,9]})
```

To help explain what I am trying to do, I have implemented u_up (the users who have clicked thumbs up) as an array of objects, and u_down (the users who have clicked down) as an array of numbers. The up and down fields are a total running count of up and down votes for that particular product.

Looking only at `u_up`, If I run the following query,

```
db.items.find({}, {up: 1, u_up: {$elemMatch: {id: 2}}})
```

Gets me back what I want.. all four items for user 2, but only populates u_up if that user has voted up. So, I'll know that he has already voted up on that particular item, and at the same time get back all the items that he hasn't voted on. I don't want to know about the rest of the users in the query result.

```
 {"_id": 2345,"up": 2,
   "u_up": [{"id": 2}]}

 {"_id": 4432,
   "up": 3,
   "u_up": [{"id": 2}]}

 {"_id": 2345,
   "up": 0}

 { "_id": 2345,
   "up": 2,
   "u_up": [{"id": 2}]}
```

It seems to be a bit wasteful to have to store an entire object for each user, and I am hoping to use an array instead (like I have implemented for u_down above).

Is there a query in mongodb that would achieve this? Or alternatively one that would return a flag or something to indicate the user has already voted up or down, but to also return the products he hasn't voted for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that this does the trick...

```
db.items.find({}, {down: 1, u_down : {$elemMatch: {$in: [9]}}})
```

Giving

```
 {"_id": 23123,
   "down": 3}

 {"_id": 34123,
   "down": 3,
   "u_down": [9]}

 {"_id": 23412,
   "down": 0}

 {"_id": 12332,
   "down": 2,
   "u_down": [9]}
```

If anyone knows how I'd covert the `u_down` in to a `true` flag with mongo, like the one below. I'd love to know.

```
 {"_id": 23412,
   "down": 0}

 {"_id": 12332,
   "down": 2,
   "u_down": true}
```

Comment: It's not documented but so does `$eq` as well `{ "u_down": { "$elemMatch": { "$eq": 9 } }}` But the real answer is that you don't need this for singular values and can just do `{ "down": 1, "u_down": 9 }`